# Error in latest @angular/fire: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I've upgraded to the latest version of @angular/fire recently, and everything worked fine, but now I've migrated away from the compat libraries, and now I'm stuck with this issue. I get this error on the following code:
`Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()`.

```
// ...
import {getAuth, provideAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {getFirestore, provideFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp} from '@angular/fire/app';
// ...

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    // ...
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(window['firebase_config'])),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
})
export class ApModule {
  // ...
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Error: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at new ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65953:33)
    at new FirebaseError (http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:166709:5)
    at ErrorFactory.create (http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:166739:19)
    at getApp (http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:122971:25)
    at getAuth (http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:137360:77)
    at http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:69140:44
    at http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:69066:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:463:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:225:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34688:28)
    at runOutsideAngular (http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:69066:33)
    at http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:69140:17
    at http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:1581:144
    at http://localhost:4200/apps_frontend_src_app_app_module_ts.js:68430:47
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:463:26)
```

I'm totally confused on why I'm getting this error. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the issue was a mismatch in versions between `firebase` and `@firebase/app`. Because of this mismatch, firebase was actually loaded into memory twice, but only instantiated once.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on mismatch in the versions? Is it the versions of 'firebase' and @firebase/app in package.json? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: If you run npm ls @firebase/app you may see that one version of Firebase comes off of AngularFire and another Firebase version could be loaded, which could cause conflicts. This depends on the order you install FirebaseTools, Firebase and AngularFire and which version of Firebase you install.

Comment: I had the issue because I installed firebase manually and then installed angularfire afterwards. In order to fix it, I uninstalled both and then just installed angularfire, which installs it's own firebase dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do an ng-update - update all pkgs listed

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) suggest that the code you put in the providers should the in the imports.

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({ ... })),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Humm.. ok, I am using version 9 upgraded from 8 in my project, and either you commented out some things or you indeed are missing some stuff. Let me share my module:

```
const providers = [
 // ...
  AngularFireModule,
  AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
  AngularFireAuthGuard,
  ScreenTrackingService,
  UserTrackingService,
  AngularFireAnalytics,
  {
    provide: ANALYTICS_CONFIG,
    useValue: {
      APP_NAME: appConfig.appName,
      APP_VERSION: appConfig.appVersion
    }
  }
];



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...

    /** Firebase Modules */
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
    AngularFireAuthGuardModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,

    // ...
  ],
  providers,
  bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
```

So my initialize app is at my imports and not on my providers, I remember I had some issues back then and after some digging and changing I came up with the above and it worked for me. As you can see I use quite a few of their services.

From the error you posted, I would guess the problem is your `initializeApp` not doing the initialization, so make try to move it to imports and make sure the config file has all the required properties.

==UPDATE==

Please note that I pasted my project imports, you may ignore everything else other than the `AngularFireModule` import and providers, since you may not use the others, I just added them for reference as they could be useful to other people.

Comment: What you are using here are the old "compat" imports. If you switch to the new modular api, you won't be using al those AngularFire*Module classes anymore

Comment: Your imports should look like this import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp, getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAuth, getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions, getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { provideStorage, getStorage, connectStorageEmulator } from '@angular/fire/storage';